# listview item said to be "Null"

Tags: c#, listview

I have a list view which is below.....
[image]

I am trying to read the **Quantity** and **Available** based on their **ProductID**

I want to read the data in the listview and then i will view the error if `Quantity > Available`

Now when ever i do so, the items are *Null*

**here is ASPnet:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvCart" runat="server" onitemcommand="lvCart_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td>
         <asp:Label ID="lbproductid" runat="server"
            class="form-control" Width="50"
            Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
    </td>
    <td>
        <%# Eval("Name") %>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltRefNo" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("RefNo") %>' Visible="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        Php <%# Eval("Price", "{0: #,###.00}") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"
            class="form-control" type="number"
            min="1" max="99" MaxLength="2" Width="70"
            Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' required />

            <asp:Label ID="avail" runat="server"
            class="form-control" Width="50"
            Text='<%# Eval("Available") %>' />
    </td>
```

**Code Behind 1:**
(here is what i tried)

```
void getavail()
{
    Label lbproductid = (Label)lvCart.FindControl("lbproductid");
    Label avail = (Label)lvCart.FindControl("avail");
    //ITemplate ID = (ITemplate)lvCart.FindControl("ProductID");
    TextBox txtQty = (TextBox)lvCart.FindControl("txtQty");

    if (int.Parse(txtQty.Text) > int.Parse(avail.Text))
    {
        error.Visible = true;
    }
    con.Close();
 }
```

**Code behind 2:**
(Second trial)

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem dataitem in lvCart.Items)
{
    Label lbproductid = (Label)lvCart.FindControl("lbproductid");
    Label avail = (Label)lvCart.FindControl("avail");
    //ITemplate ID = (ITemplate)lvCart.FindControl("ProductID");
    TextBox txtQty = (TextBox)lvCart.FindControl("txtQty");

    if (int.Parse(txtQty.Text) > int.Parse(avail.Text))
    {
        error.Visible = true;
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

When trying the second codes, it does not read codes after it. Starting at the line:

```
Label lbproductid = (Label)lvCart.FindControl("lbproductid");
```

and then it directs to last bracket and *close();*

I am putting this GetAvail in the page load event as i want it to show right away.

help this got me hours. thanks in advance

Comment: Whenever code appears to magically skip lines, it's probably throwing an exception which is being silently handled: `lvCart` might be null, and the result might not be a `Label`.

Comment: You're looping `dataitem`, but never using it. Should you be calling `FindControl` on `dataitem` rather than on `lvCart`? You're also closing `con` on the first iteration (it should probably be outside the foreach)

Comment: @Rob listview has data being showed in the web.

Comment: how in the lvcart? i want it to show when page loads.